# Query WorldClim using R to obtain data set of Earth's terrestrial surface only?

Tags: r, geospatial

WorldClim can be queried from R by:

```
    library(geodata)

    df <- worldclim_global(var="bio",res = 2.5, path ="")
```

df will necessarily include all of Earth's land and ocean surface. Is there an efficient way to separate the two? I'd like to sample from land alone - so removing areas covered by large lakes/rivers and glaciers will need to happen as well. It is imperative that the land's surface be the global extent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have determined a solution for isolating the spatial extent of planet Earth that is not under the ocean, lakes, or glaciers. The following script will generate that extent for you - though some modification may be required.

For this code to be useful, you will need to download spatial data from NaturalEarth: https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/. At the website, search for these files and download them to your computer in your working directory for your project. The files: ne_10m_land.shp, dd_land.rda,ne_10m_glaciated_areas.shp, and dd_lake.rda.

What is generated by this code can be used to extract information in a raster falling within the spatial extent created and then that data saved in a different raster (or some other format). There are several good examples for how to do that here in stackoverflow.

```
    ###
    # Keeping tidy
    
    # rm(list=ls(all=T))
    # gc()
    # .rs.restartR()
    # rm(list=ls(all=T))
    # gc()
    
    library(spatialEco)
    library(sf)
    library(ggOceanMaps)
    library(rgeos)
    library(scattermore)
    library(maptools)
    library(rgdal)
    library(sp)
    library(plyr)
    library(dplyr)
    library(raster)
    library(rgdal)
    library(geodata)
    library(exactextractr)
    
    
    # where data is stored
    NEDPath <- outPath <- ""  # I used data from Natural Earth:
    #https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/
    #you'll need the following files from there for this code to work:
    #ne_10m_land.shp, dd_land.rda,ne_10m_glaciated_areas.shp, and
    #dd_lake.rda
    # 
    # # call in the world's terrestrial surface
    continental <- st_read(file.path(NEDPath, 
"ne_10m_land/ne_10m_land.shp"))
        islands <- st_read(file.path(NEDPath, "ne_10m_minor_islands/ne_10m_minor_islands.shp"))
        world <- rbind(continental,islands)
        dd_land <- clip_shapefile(world, c(-180, 180, -90, 90))
        save(dd_land, file = paste(outPath, "ggOceanMapsData/dd_land.rda", sep = "/"), compress = "xz")

    
    # call in glacier coverage
    glaciers <- st_read(file.path(NEDPath, "ne_10m_glaciated_areas/ne_10m_glaciated_areas.shp"))
    glaciers <- as_Spatial(glaciers)
    glaciers <- gBuffer(glaciers, byid = TRUE, width = 0)
    dd_glacier <- clip_shapefile(glaciers, c(-180, 180, -90, 90))
    dd_glacier <- gBuffer(dd_glacier, byid = FALSE, width = 0.1)
    dd_glacier <- gBuffer(dd_glacier, byid = FALSE, width = -0.1)
    save(dd_glacier, file = paste(outPath, "ggOceanMapsData/dd_glacier.rda", sep = "/"), compress = "xz")
    
    # call in lakes
    lake <- st_read(file.path(NEDPath, "ne_10m_lakes/ne_10m_lakes.shp"))
    lake <- as_Spatial(lake)
    lake <- gBuffer(lake, byid = TRUE, width = 0)
    dd_lake <- clip_shapefile(lake, c(-180, 180, -90, 90))
    dd_lake <- gBuffer(dd_lake, byid = FALSE, width = 0.1)
    dd_lake <- gBuffer(dd_lake, byid = FALSE, width = -0.1)
    save(dd_lake, file = paste(outPath, "ggOceanMapsData/dd_lake.rda", sep = "/"), compress = "xz")
    
    # isolating extent of world's surface not covered by ice or water
    terrestrial <- gDifference(dd_land, dd_lake)
    terrestrial_ice_free <- gDifference(terrestrial, dd_glacier)
    save(terrestrial_ice_free, file = paste(outPath, "ggOceanMapsData/landsurface.rda", sep = "/"), compress = "xz")
    
    # call the files if saved already, if saved, you can comment out the all the code above until where the working directory is defined - this will save you a lot of time...
    load(file = paste(outPath, "ggOceanMapsData/dd_land.rda", sep = "/"))
    load(file = paste(outPath, "ggOceanMapsData/dd_glacier.rda", sep = "/"))
    load(file = paste(outPath, "ggOceanMapsData/dd_lake.rda", sep = "/"))
    load(file = paste(outPath, "ggOceanMapsData/landsurface.rda", sep = "/"))
    
    # for convenience
    land<-terrestrial_ice_free
```